# how to custmize font awasome icons using cheat sheet in css?

Tags: css

I am designing a contact form. I want to add font awasome icons in input fields. I am adding icons by using cheat sheet of font icons in external css.I want to adjust the size of icons using cheat code.

My CSS code is this-

```
 .wpcf7-form span
    {
    position: relative; /* Helps curtail overlap */
    border: solid 1px #bbb;
    padding: 3px 5px 5px 25px; /* Adjust as needed */
    }
    .wpcf7-form span.input {
    border: none;
    }
    .wpcf7-form span:before {
    content: '\fa-2x f206';
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    color: #888; /* Your desired color */
    }
```

HTML is-

```
<p>[text* your-name placeholder "Name"] </p>

<p>[email* your-email placeholder "Email"]</p>

<p>[tel* tel-427 placeholder "Phone"]</p>

<p>[textarea your-message placeholder "Message"] </p>

<p style="text-align:right;">[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css, you can change the icon size using font-size option.

Usage : '.fa.fa-icon* {
           font-size : 1em (or in px);
         }`

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome provides with options to set the size of the ico. They provide from 1x to 5x. You can choose the right size for your form.

Comment: Ya I know but I want to change the size of font icons by using css(CHEAT SHEET).